# MySql Get Balance Query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following tables and I am struggling to get the right query:

ACTIVITY TABLE:

```
ID   USER_ID    CARD_ID    CLOCK
1      123        04675545   4/3/2013 1:07:06 PM
2      123        04675545   4/3/2013 2:08:06 PM
3      124        04675550   4/3/2013 2:07:06 PM
4      124        04675550   4/3/2013 4:07:06 PM
```

**
PRICE TABLE:

```
ID    FROMTIME    TOTIME       PRICEPERHOUR
1     08:00:00    19:59:59     50.00
2     20:00:00    07:59:59     75.00
```

I am trying to create a procedure that will tell me how much each user has spend on a daily basis based on the amount charge per hour and the total activity for each day. Once I have the right query I will then insert that into a transaction table.

Any ideas on what would be the best practice for this? thanks a lot to whoever can help.

Comment: plz, provide the ideal result you want to get for this test data. Then it would be easier for us to write the query.

Comment: Can you please confirm your Activity Table, I don't think @Meherzad's answer actually considers it...  First record would be when user STARTS a job, second record is when they FINISHED the job.  So, for UserID = 123, they worked for 1hour, 1 minute.  Does this get charged as two hours?  any margin to be ignored (such as 5 minutes?)... For User 124, they have a two-hour span of work performed.   In addition, if a person starts at 17:00 and ends at 21:00, they have 3 hrs at 50 and 1 hr at 75.  Would this be correct?

Comment: @DRapp thanks for pointing..... have edited the answer accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

Try this query

If you want to create stored procedure you can create from the given query...

### EDITED

```
select a.user_id, date(a.clock),  ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.clock, b.clock))/3600)*c.PRICEPERHOUR as total from 
(Select if((@rn:=@rn+1)%2=0,@rn,@rn-1) As rId, act.* from act
join
(select @rn:=-1)a
order by user_Id, clock) a 
inner join 
(Select if((@rn1:=@rn1+1)%2=0,@rn1,@rn1-1) As rId, act.* from act
join
(select @rn1:=-1)b
order by user_Id, clock) b
ON a.rid=b.rid AND a.id <> b.id 
inner join 
price c
on 
TIME_TO_SEC(a.clock) between TIME_TO_SEC(c.FROMTIME) 
AND 
TIME_TO_SEC(c.TOTIME)
group by a.user_id, date(a.clock)
```

**Results**:

```
| USER_ID |                DATE(A.CLOCK) |   TOTAL |
----------------------------------------------------
|     123 | April, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 50.8333 |
|     124 | April, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |     100 |
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/422d9/28/0)**

Comment: @carol1287 pl check the edited answer...

Comment: Thank you so much user4035, DRapp and Meherzad for your help and apologize for the late response. Excellent point @DRapp, sorry for missing this important information. Answered to your question, if the user works for 1hour, 1 minute, it should be charged only 1 minute from the hour. If the  user works 1 hour and 59 minutes it should be charger also 1 hour and 59 minutes. So it needs to calculate the equivalent amount for 59 minutes from the hour. If a person starts at 17:00 and ends at 21:00, they have 3 hrs at 50 and 1 hr at 75, that will be correct.

Comment: thanks so much for the query. I have run it but I get 0 results :(. I have followed your example and replaced act.* with activity.* (table name) but still I get no results.

Comment: correction, actually I do get the results, really sorry as I made a mistake and missed the a.id <> b.id part. again sorry about this, I was trying to understand this part: rn:=rn because I am not familiar with this type of syntax and I didn't notice the error. If I understand well your query, it does exactly what I want because it calculates the percentage amount within a given hour, is that correct?

Comment: @carol1287 Got your problem will work on it later on..  The current solution only takes into consideration the `fromTime` and gets the total cost...